Checkbox Toggle current value
I am using the standard Salesforce Toggle checkbox code.
I am not able to read the current value of the toggle with getelementbyId.
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
<span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Toggle Label</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-19" value="checkbox-toggle-19" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-19" />
<span id="checkbox-toggle-19" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container">
<span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
<span class="slds-checkbox_on">Enabled</span>
<span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disabled</span>
</span>
</label>
</div>


In LWC, ID values should be considered unreliable.
Alternatives include using lwc:ref:
<input lwc:ref="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-19" value="checkbox-toggle-19" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-19" />

...
let isMyCheckboxChecked = this.refs.myCheckbox.checked;

Or if this dynamic, query by some other value instead:
let myCheckbox = this.template.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');


Thank you. I am using this in Vlocity framework. Template in angular JS. Any suggestions on that?
